# How do I record the desktop sounds and microphone in separated tracks and at same time

Tags: sound, microphone, audio-recording, audacity

I am trying to record the microphone and desktop sounds with Audacity in separated tracks, but in `pavucontrol` only I can select or "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" (the desktop) or "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" (the microphone).

Well, it is not necesary to record in Audacity but I want to record in separated tracks or audio files these two sounds sources and of course I want to start simultaneously to record.

How do I it on Audacity or other app?